# Why image is blur in camera view

Tags: camera

I have uv wrap the image looks good in the texture mode. When set in the camera  view look blur to the side. I applied scale rotation. I used uv mapping and texture coordinator to control but yet no result i found How can i fix.

[image]

[image]

Comment: It looks like the image has low resolution.

Comment: in texture mode it looks good. File is attach plz go through

Comment: First of all this texture is pretty small, it's only 1024x638px. Secondly the effect you are talking about is not blur but rather flatness. It's become visible because of camera distance from the ground and it's angle. With good lightning and some bumps/normal map it should look ok.

Comment: Look like anisotropic filtering